# Difference between downcasting of classes and foreach variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have such classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int AProperty { get; set; }
    public List<A> Children;
}

public class B:A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I **cannot** do this:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;//SystemCastInvalidException
```

I **can** do this:

```
B bCanDo= new B();
bCanDo.Children.Add(new B());       

foreach (var c in bCanDo.Children)
{
   B notExpected = (B)c;//OKAY. Why? 
}
```

What I miss out? Why I can downcast in `foreach`? yeah, it is all logically correct, but where I can read info about it?

Comment: I assume you ment `foreach (var c in b.Children)`, don´t you?

Comment: The difference is, `c` actually *is*  of type `B`, while `a` is of type `A`.

Comment: You should clean up your example slightly, I am assuming that `bCanDo` is a variable of type `A`  or that it is supposed to be `b` ?

Comment: @Corak The type of the variable `c` is `A`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - yes, but the object `c` is refering to is actually of type `B`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, it is a `B`, as he´s adding it to the `Children` of `b` before.

Comment: @StepUp: if you change your "can do" example to include b.Children.Add(new A()), then it will blow up with an exception during the loop.  It's the _actual_ type of the objects, not the declared type that matters

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah, it is supposed to be `B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a runtime error, not a compiler error, so let's look at what you're doing here:

In the first example you're constructing an object of type `A`, then try to cast it to type `B`. This is illegal since `A` does not inherit from `B`. It is **not** illegal because the *compiler* thinks this, it compiles the code, then it crashes at runtime because this is definitely an invalid cast.

In the second example, however, you're constructing an object of type `B` and then adding it to a list that can hold objects of type `A`. Since `B` inherits from `A` this is legal. You then pick the first object back out and cast it to `B`. This is also legal since the underlying object is actually of type `B`.

Basically, here's your two examples with more minimal steps:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a; // fails with InvalidCastException

A a = new B();
B b = (B)a; // works OK
```

So this has nothing to do with foreach, it has everything to do with your two examples *doing different things*. To see the same code fail with `foreach`, try this:

```
B bCanDo= new B();
bCanDo.Children.Add(new A()); // <-- notice new A() here

foreach (var c in bCanDo.Children)
{
   B notExpected = (B)c; // crash
}
```

So while you can downcast an object reference to a more derived type this will only work if the actual object being reference is that derived type (or an even more derived type down that path). Basically this is a reference reinterpretation, you're just putting on new glasses while looking at the same object.

You cannot downcast an object instance to a more derived type if it isn't of that derived type, however, this would be a conversion and requires explicit support or code to be written to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the cannot-case, a contains an object of Type A which cannot be cast to B since it A is not of type B.

In the can-case the an object of type B is added to the children, since B is a sub-type of A you can do this but it remains an object of type B. When you loop the children and cast it to B, you are only able to do so because it already is a B. Would you add `b.Children.Add(new A());` it would fail again.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is that casting doesn't change the underlying object in any way.

So if I have these classes:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
```

...and I write this code:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Animal a = (Animal)d;
```

The `a` variable is still a `Dog`, it's just being acted upon as if it were just an `Animal`.

If I defined this class:

```
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

...and I tried to then write this code:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Cat c = (Cat)d;
```

...I get an error, but not because I can't change a `Dog` to a `Cat`, instead it is because the object `d` is always a `Dog` and I can't treat it as if it were a `Cat`. A `Dog` can never be a `Cat`.

So in your code when you write:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;//SystemCastInvalidException
```

...the same applies - a `A` can never be a `B`.

But in your code a `B` **can** be an `A`.

So if I re-write your code slightly as this:

```
B bCanDo = new B();
bCanDo.Children.Add(new B());

foreach (A a in bCanDo.Children)
{
    B notExpected = (B)a; 
}
```

...you can see that even though the `Children` of `bCanDo` are type `A` you can add children of type `B` - a `B` **can** be an `A`. So when you iterate through the `Children` the types of the children never change so, even though the members of `Children` are `A`, if a `B` was added you can always cast it back to `B`. This is why the `foreach` cast works.